# Converting oracle cursor to jpa criteria query

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I there way to write this cursor in java jpa  criteria query...

```
   cursor main_1 is

    select join_date,sum(tot_sal),emp_name
    from emp_datail,emp_join
    where emp_id=emp_join_id and join_date=to_date('14/02/2015','dd/mm/yyyy')
    and per_sal>100000
    group by join_date,emp_name
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> cq = cb.createQuery(Object[].class);
    Root<Org> orgRoot = cq.from(Org.class);
    Join<Org, Dept> ord = orgRoot.join("dept");
    cq.multiselect(orgRoot.get("orgname"), ord.get("deptname"),
            cb.sum(ord.<Integer> get("deptamt"))).groupBy(
            orgRoot.get("orgname"));

    Query qry = em.createQuery(cq);
    List<Object[]> orgList = qry.getResultList();
```